Building Infra on AWS using terraform for a multiaccount project
Building Infra on AWS using Terraform for a multiaccount project, where I need to build some eks, vpcs, rds, elastic cache and cross functional roles , I am roles and all other required components. Has someone previously worked on these requirements or can you please direct me to a useful repo with similar tf files? any help is appreciated.
